# Find surface area of revolution of $\sin x + \cos x$ around $x$-axis?

Tags: calculus

Specifically, what is the surface area of revolution of the function y = sin(x)+ cos(x) about the x-axis on the interval from $\frac{\pi}{4}$ and $\frac{5\pi}{4}$? The answer I got from Wolfram Alpha is approx. 3.5957. However, I am having trouble solving the integral itself after setting it up. I would greatly appreciate it if you could provide the steps so I can solve future problems of this type. Thanks.

EDIT: I think the integral should be $$2\pi\int_{\pi/4}^{5\pi/4}|(\sin x +\cos x )|\sqrt{2-\sin 2x }$$ but I am not entirely sure how to solve it.

Comment: What is the integral you are trying to solve?

Comment: I just made an edit :)

Comment: It might simplify things a bit to rewrite $y$ as $\sqrt{2} \cos(x-\pi/4)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $y(x) = \cos x+\sin x$, the surface integral is

$$S= 2\pi\int_{\pi/4}^{5\pi/4} |y|\sqrt{1+(y_x')^2}dx
=4\pi\int_{\pi/4}^{3\pi/4} y\sqrt{1+(y_x')^2}dx$$

Let $t=y_x' = -\sin x + \cos x$, which leads to $dt = -(\cos x + \sin x)dx = -ydx$. Then, the integral becomes,

$$S = 4\pi\int_{0}^{\sqrt2} \sqrt{1+t^2}dt = 2\pi(\sqrt6 +\sinh^{-1}\sqrt2)$$

where the integral is solved with the substitution $t=\sinh u$.

Comment: Just to clarify, the upper bound becomes $-\sqrt(2)$ after the t substitution correct? And this becomes positive when you plug in the substitution for dx?

Comment: @The boyboy - That is correct